# Encoding En Dash character on C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, character-encoding

I have a text file which include en dash "–" character. When i read the file and output with encodings it returns to ? character. I tried Utf8, ASCII, UTF32, UTF7, Unicode and default.

sample txt includes;

```
000020a3;LH 10000924 – 000 – 08;Formal;&&&
```

Here is my code below;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\fullfilepath\sample.txt", Encoding.Default);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output;

```
000020a3;LH 10000924 ? 000 ? 08;Formal;&&&
```

Comment: Your terminal is screwing up I think. `Console.OutputEndoding = Encoding.Default`. AIthough you should probably use `Encoding.Uft8` explicitly (in both places) -- `Encoding.Default` means different things in .NET Framework and .NET Core / .NET 5+

Comment: I'd try [`Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-7.0#system-text-encoding-getencoding(system-int32))